# What are the relative strong and weak points between tcolorbox and mdframed?

Tags: mdframed, tcolorbox

I think practically we will not use both `tcolorbox` and `mdframed` in a single input file. Correct me if I am wrong. So we have to choose either `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`. However, without knowing the strong and weak points of both, we can only choose one by gambling.

Shortly speaking, what are the weak and strong points of both packages? The answers really influence the path of my life in TeX.

Comment: I remember Marco Daniel saying that `tcolorbox` is more advanced than `mdframed`. My memory may bad though. Kindly excuse if I am wrong.

Comment: related: [`framed` or `mdframed`? (Pros/Cons)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71554/5049)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I have the understanding that `tcolorbox` capabilities are a superset of `mdframed`. While `mdframed` tries to give you tools to create colorful frames, they look pale and simpler to me comparing to `tcolorbox` ones.

I think with enough `tikz` ninja skills you can achieve pretty much what you want with both, but somehow the `tcolorbox` syntax and options are simpler to me.

Also, `tcolorbox` has this "upper part/lower part" capabilities that `mdframed` lacks and creating a simple colored frame with a title seems simpler with `tcolorbox`.

From the documentation of **mdframed**

```
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
linecolor=red,middlelinewidth=2pt,%
frametitlerule=true,%
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfframetitlebackground/.append style={%
shade,left color=white, right color=blue!20}}},
frametitlerulecolor=green!60,
frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
}
\mdtheorem[style=theoremstyle]{definition}{Definition}
\begin{definition}[Inhomogeneous linear]
\ExampleText
\end{definition}
\begin{definition*}[Inhomogeneous linear]
\ExampleText
\end{definition*}
```

[image: mdframed theorem]

the equivalent in **tcolorbox** documentation:

```
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{mytheo}{My Theorem}%
{colback=green!5,colframe=green!35!black,fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\begin{mytheo}{This is my title}{theoexample}
This is the text of the theorem. The counter is automatically assigned and,
in this example, prefixed with the section number. This theorem is numbered with
\ref{th:theoexample} and is given on page \pageref{th:theoexample}.
\end{mytheo}
```

[image: tcolorbox theorem]

@claudio-fiandrino mentioned that mdframe boxes can be customized with tikz. This is also the case with tcolorbox, since it relies on tikz.

```
\tcbset{colback=Salmon!50!white,colframe=FireBrick!75!black, width=(\linewidth-8mm)/2,before=,after=\hfill,equal height group=ske}
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=My title]
This is my content.
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[skin=beamer,beamer,adjusted title=My title]
This is my content.
\end{tcolorbox}
```

[image: tcolorbox customization]

Comment: Actually, like `tikz`, the `tcolorbox` package relies on `pgf`, a lower level framework. But Tikz support can be loaded as a library.

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth: I've been using `mdframed` for quite a while… I didn't know `tcolorbox` existed! After browsing the `tcolorbox` documentation for a couple of minutes, I'm itching to convert my documents.

It seems to me like an extremely well-crafted package. It is natively based on `pgf`, and uses `pgfkeys` properly to provide its own range of options, which is to me a mark of quality. It also offers a suite of libraries to extend functionality, such as full `tikz` support.

In contrast, the `mdframed` interface has always felt a bit clumsy and frustrating to me. And support for custom TikZ options seems to be 'tacked on', rather than properly implemented. In addition, I've had it conflict with other packages on more than one occasion.

Answer (score 2):

I read little doc about `tcolorbox`, and some doc on `mdframed`, i mainly use `mdframed` for my environments. In my opinion, one can change frameline with `mdframed` using `tikz/pgf` easily, there are many illustrations on [stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) given by [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) and someone else. As for `tcolorbox`, it seems that there is little example code, but the `tcolorbox`'s documentation is very beautifully made.

Comment: Also `tcolorbox` allows to easily change the so called _skin_ with custom TikZ/PGF frames.

Comment: i have changed my mind, tcolorbox is flexible

Answer (score 0):

Another point against `mdframed`: breakable boxes can make bad break sometimes.

See an example below.

[image]
⋅
[image]

(example taken from [How to prevent mdframed from typesetting a widow line that contains just a bit vspace with colored background?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241543/250119))

Various [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545329/mdframed-package-warning-you-got-a-bad-break?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1377467_545329) suggests using `tcolorbox` instead.