# How to prevent mdframed from typesetting a widow line that contains just a bit vspace with colored background?

Tags: page-breaking, mdframed

The code below produces a nice box around an equation or a few lines of text but continues the boxes on the following page with an absurd horizontal rule.
Of course I can get rid of this outrageous page break by adding

```
nobreak=true,
```

to `\newmdenv`; but for other, larger boxes I will need page breaks. Therefore I need another solution to fix this undesirable behavior of mdframed.

Here the code example, about as minimal as I could get it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{report}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{430pt}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math} % must come after ams and symbols

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdenv[
usetwoside=false,
skipabove=3pt minus 1pt plus 3pt,
skipbelow=3pt minus 1pt plus 3pt,
leftmargin=-4pt,
rightmargin=-4pt,
innerleftmargin=2pt,
innerrightmargin=2pt,
innertopmargin=4pt,
innerbottommargin=4pt,
backgroundcolor=\boxcolor!20,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=\boxcolor,
linewidth=2pt,
]{aux*}

\newenvironment{mybox} {\begin{aux*}} {\end{aux*}}

\begin{document}

Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
and now the problematic box
\def\boxcolor{green}
\begin{mybox}%
\begin{equation}\label{Edwba}
  \sum
\end{equation}%
\end{mybox}
See just above the nonsensical line produced by mdframed!
\begin{equation}ab\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}ab\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}ab\end{equation}
\begin{equation}ab\end{equation}

\def\boxcolor{red}
\begin{mybox}%
  Here comes an example with three lines of text in the box.
  Three lines is a lot of text bla bla bla bla bla bla blaaa.
  Three lines is a lot of text bla bla bla bla bla bla blaaa.
\end{mybox}

See again the scandalous page break.

\end{document}
```

And here the screenshots of the generated three pages:

[image]

--

[image]

--

[image]

Comment: I guess that the problem is that after `equation` a new line starts. Can you use the box inside `equation`?

Comment: The same problem occurs if `mybox` contains text. Hence the equation environment definitively has nothing to do with the problem. Maybe I should have chosen a text example to present my question in simpler form.

Comment: OK, you can edit the post to add a minimal full code reproducing the problem so we can compile it.

Comment: Please fix the example so it can be run locally to show the problem.  Hard to debug otherwise.

Comment: OK, now the question comes with a working example.

Comment: The package does detect this and warn, but presumably it can only detect it too late, you get multiple warnings such as `Package mdframed Warning: You got a bad break
(mdframed)                because the last split box is empty
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package detects this and warns that the final frame segment at the page break is empty. It does however output the segment, otherwise you would not get the 
final border of the frame.

here though you only have side borders so (I think, I don't know this code that well) it is safe just to discard the final segment. It seems to work here at least. (See the two places marked `CHANGE`)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{report}

\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{430pt}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[bold-style=ISO]{unicode-math} % must come after ams and symbols

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\makeatletter

\def\mdf@put@frame@ii{%
  \setlength{\mdf@freevspace@length}{\vsize}%
    \ifbool{mdf@repeatframetitle}%
      {%repeating title -- more robust using hooks.
       \toggletrue{mdf@notfirstframetitle}%
       \splitmaxdepth\z@ \splittopskip\z@%
       \setbox\mdf@splitbox@one=\vbox{\break\unvbox\mdf@splitbox@one}%
       \mdf@ignorevbadness%
       \setbox0=\vsplit\mdf@splitbox@one to \z@\relax%
       \setbox\mdf@splitbox@one=\vbox{\unvbox\mdf@splitbox@one}%
       \setbox\mdf@splitbox@one\vbox%
          {%
           \parskip\z@\relax%
           \parindent\z@\relax%
           \vskip\mdf@frametitleaboveskip@length%
           \unvcopy\mdf@frametitlebox\relax%
           \mdf@@frametitlerule\relax%
           \unvbox\mdf@splitbox@one\relax%
          }%
       \setbox\mdf@splitbox@one=\vbox{\unvbox\mdf@splitbox@one}%
      }{}%
  \setlength{\dimen@}{\dimexpr\ht\mdf@splitbox@one+\dp\mdf@splitbox@one\relax}%
  \mdf@dolist{\mdf@advancelength@add{\dimen@}}%
        {innerbottommargin,innerlinewidth,middlelinewidth,outerlinewidth}%
  \ifboolexpr { bool {mdf@everyline} and bool {mdf@topline} }%
    {%
     \mdf@dolist{\mdf@advancelength@add{\dimen@}}%
        {innerlinewidth,middlelinewidth,outerlinewidth}%
    }{}%
   \notbool{mdf@bottomline}%remove bottom if neccessary
     {%
       \mdf@dolist{\mdf@advancelength@sub{\dimen@}}%
         {innerlinewidth,middlelinewidth,outerlinewidth}%
     }{}%
   \ifdimgreater{\dimen@}{\mdf@freevspace@length}%
    {%have a middle box
     \advance\mdf@freevspace@length by -\mdf@splitbottomskip@length\relax%
     \ifbool{mdf@everyline}%regard top and bottom if everyline is used
       {%
        \ifbool{mdf@topline}%
          {%
           \mdf@dolist{\mdf@advancelength@sub{\mdf@freevspace@length}}%
             {innerlinewidth,middlelinewidth,outerlinewidth}%
          }{}%
        \ifbool{mdf@bottomline}%
          {%
           \mdf@dolist{\mdf@advancelength@sub{\mdf@freevspace@length}}%
             {innerlinewidth,middlelinewidth,outerlinewidth}%
          }{}%
       }{}%
     \setbox\mdf@splitbox@save=\vbox{\unvcopy\mdf@splitbox@one}%
     \splitmaxdepth\z@ \splittopskip\mdf@splittopskip@length%
     \mdf@ignorevbadness%
     \setbox\mdf@splitbox@two\vsplit\mdf@splitbox@one to \mdf@freevspace@length%
     \setbox\mdf@splitbox@two\vbox{\unvbox\mdf@splitbox@two}%
     \setbox\mdf@splitbox@one\vbox{\unvbox\mdf@splitbox@one}%
     \ifdimgreater{\ht\mdf@splitbox@two+\dp\mdf@splitbox@two}%
                  {\mdf@freevspace@length}%
       {%splitted wrong
        \mdf@PackageInfo{Box was splittet wrong^^J
                         starting loop to iterate
                         the splitting point\MessageBreak}%
        \dimen@i=\mdf@freevspace@length%\relax
        \@tempcnta=\z@\relax
        \loop
        \ifdim\dimexpr\ht\mdf@splitbox@two+\dp\mdf@splitbox@two\relax>%
              \mdf@freevspace@length\relax
          \advance\dimen@i by -\p@\relax%
          \advance\@tempcnta by \@ne\relax%
          \ifnum\@tempcnta>100
            \let\iterate\relax%
            \mdf@PackageWarning{correct box splittet fails^^J
                                It seems you are using a non splittable
                                contents\MessageBreak}%
          \fi
          \mdf@ignorevbadness%
          \setbox\mdf@splitbox@one=\vbox{\unvcopy\mdf@splitbox@save}%
          \splitmaxdepth\z@ \splittopskip\mdf@splittopskip@length%
          \mdf@ignorevbadness%
          \setbox\mdf@splitbox@two\vsplit\mdf@splitbox@one to \dimen@i\relax%
          \setbox\mdf@splitbox@two\vbox{\unvbox\mdf@splitbox@two}%
          \setbox\mdf@splitbox@one\vbox{\unvbox\mdf@splitbox@one}%
        \repeat%
       }{}%
     \ifvoid\mdf@splitbox@one\relax%
        \mdf@PackageWarning{You got a bad break because the splittet box is
                            empty^^J
                            You have to change the page settings^^J
                            like enlargethispage or something else^^J
                            the package increases do
                            \enlargethispage{\baselineskip}\MessageBreak}%
        \setbox\mdf@splitbox@one=\vbox{\unvcopy\mdf@splitbox@save}%
        \enlargethispage{\baselineskip}%
        \def\mdf@reserved@a{\mdf@put@frame@ii}%
     \else
      \setbox\mdf@splitbox@two=\vbox%
                   {%
                    \hrule \@height\z@ \@width\mdfboundingboxwidth\relax%
                    \unvcopy\mdf@splitbox@two%
                   }%
        \begingroup%
          \mdf@@setzref%
          \booltrue{mdfmiddleframe}%
          \mdf@beforebreak%
          \mdf@putbox@middle%
          \mdf@afterbreak%
        \endgroup%
          \hrule \@height\z@ \@width\hsize%
          \vfill\eject%
          \def\mdf@reserved@a{\mdf@put@frame@ii}%
        \fi
     }%End middle box case
     {%start last box case
      \ifvoid\mdf@splitbox@one
           \mdf@PackageWarning{You got a bad break\MessageBreak
                               because the last split box is empty\MessageBreak
                               You have to change the settings1}%%
%CHANGE:  leave final box as void
\iffalse
 \setbox\mdf@splitbox@one=\vbox%
                  {%
                   \unvbox\mdf@splitbox@one%
                   \hrule \@height\z@ \@width\mdfboundingboxwidth
                  }%
\fi
%end CHANGE
      \fi%
      \ifdimless{\ht\mdf@splitbox@one}{1sp}%
         {%
          \mdf@PackageWarning{You got a bad break\MessageBreak
                              because the last split box is empty\MessageBreak
                              You have to change the settings2}%

          \let\mdf@reserved@a\relax%
%CHANGE: add discard final box
\iffalse
 \setbox\mdf@splitbox@one=\vbox%
                 {%
                  \unvbox\mdf@splitbox@one%
                  \hrule \@height\z@ \@width\mdfboundingboxwidth
                 }%
\fi
%END CHANGE
\setbox\mdf@splitbox@one\box\voidb@x
         }{}%
      \begingroup%
      \toggletrue{mdflastframe}%
      \mdf@beforebreak%
      \begingroup%
        \mdf@@setzref%
        \booltrue{mdflastframe}%
        \mdf@beforelastframe%
        \mdf@putbox@second%
        \mdf@afterlastframe%
      \endgroup%
      \hrule \@height\z@ \@width\hsize%
      \mdf@afterbreak%
      \endgroup%
      \let\mdf@reserved@a\relax%
     }%
  \mdf@reserved@a%
}

\makeatother





\newmdenv[
usetwoside=false,
skipabove=3pt minus 1pt plus 3pt,
skipbelow=3pt minus 1pt plus 3pt,
leftmargin=-4pt,
rightmargin=-4pt,
innerleftmargin=2pt,
innerrightmargin=2pt,
innertopmargin=4pt,
innerbottommargin=4pt,
backgroundcolor=\boxcolor!20,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
linecolor=\boxcolor,
linewidth=2pt,
]{aux*}

\newenvironment{mybox} {\begin{aux*}} {\end{aux*}}

\begin{document}

Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
and now the problematic box
\def\boxcolor{green}
\begin{mybox}%
\begin{equation}\label{Edwba}
  \sum
\end{equation}%
\end{mybox}
See just above the nonsensical line produced by mdframed!
\begin{equation}ab\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}\frac{a}{b}\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}ab\end{equation}
Mix text and equation to insert lots of glue
\begin{equation}ab\end{equation}
\begin{equation}ab\end{equation}

\def\boxcolor{red}
\begin{mybox}%
  Here comes an example with three lines of text in the box.
  Three lines is a lot of text bla bla bla bla bla bla blaaa.
  Three lines is a lot of text bla bla bla bla bla bla blaaa.
\end{mybox}

See again the scandalous page break.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. Also works for my original application. Thanks.

Comment: Is that something the macro author should note? https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed

Comment: Good point. I reported the issue at https://github.com/marcodaniel/mdframed/issues/22.