# mdframed package warning: you got a bad break

Tags: mdframed

When I try to compile my main.tex file, the code inside a frame created with the mdframed package behaves weirdly and gives the following warning:

*"Package mdframed Warning: You got a bad break because the last box will be empty you have to change it manually by changing the text, the space or something else on input line 3775."*

This is the framed code:

```
\begin{mdframed}
\textbf{Remarks:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item In general $\hat{y}(t|t-1,\theta)$ depends on previous predictions $\rightarrow$ initialization is required $\rightarrow$ transient effect $\rightarrow$ the predictor is asymptotically optimal.

    Let's explain why. For ARMAX models we have $G(z^{-1})=\frac{B(z^{-1})}{A(z^{-1})}$ and $H(z^{-1})=\frac{C(z^{-1})}{A(z^{-1})}$, so the predictor will be:
    \begin{equation*}
        \hat{y}(t|t-1,\theta)=\left(1-\frac{A(z^{-1})}{C(z^{-1})}\right)y(t)+\frac{B(z^{-1})}{C(z^{-1})}u(t)
    \end{equation*}
    In this case the optimal predictor is a dynamic system itself:
    \begin{equation*}
        C(z^{-1})\hat{y}(t|t-1,\theta)=\left(C(z^{-1})-A(z^{-1})\right)y(t)+B(z^{-1})u(t)
    \end{equation*}
    When we apply the operator $z^{-1}$ we obtain the previous prediction:
    \begin{align*}
        \hat{y}(t|t-1,\theta)&=-c_1 \hat{y}(t-1|t-2,\theta)-c_2 \hat{y}(t-2|t-3,\theta)-\dots-c_n \hat{y}(t-n|t-n-1,\theta)+\\
        &+(c_1-a_1)y(t-1)+\dots+(c_n-a_n)y(t-n)+b_1 u(t-1)+\dots+b_n u(t-n)
    \end{align*}
    The problem is that if we are at time $t-1$ and we want to predict the value of $y(t)$ we need all previous input output samples, all the parameters $a_i,b_i,c_i$ (where $i=1,\dots,n$) and all the previous predictions. When we compute the prediction at the starting point we haven't all this information, so we must initialize the system and we will have a transient effect and for this reason the predictor will be optimal only asymptotically.

    Since $C(z^{-1})$ is at the denominator in the expression of the predictor and it has to be a stationary process, so we need that all the roots must be within the unitary circle (those of $C(z^{-1})$ as well).

    A rough way to start can be: start to consider the predictions from time $t=1$ (so after $n+1$ steps) and set to zero the previous predictions.

    \item In general, the $\hat{\theta}$ minimizing $J(\theta)$ cannot be found analytically (no closed-form solutions available), so we are forced to apply iterative identification algorithms (e.g. Newton-Raphson algorithm).
\end{itemize}
\end{mdframed}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to avoid this behavior still using the mdframed package? I searched for similar questions but none of them received a proper answer (if not the advice to change package).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: "change the package" is imho the only right answer. I fighted once in project with the problem to get behaving breakable boxes with mdframed and since then only use tcolorbox for this task. mdframed hasn't been updated for 7 years now.

Comment: Already `Ulrike` gave better suggestion, also the package `framed` can meet your requirement in a better way...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Since I don't need fancy frames (at the moment) I decided to use the package `framed` to keep it simple.

Comment: Very similar question: [page breaking - How to prevent mdframed from typesetting a widow line that contains just a bit vspace with colored background? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241543/how-to-prevent-mdframed-from-typesetting-a-widow-line-that-contains-just-a-bit-v)

Answer (score 1):

You can otherwise simply put it inside a

```
\begin{figure}[H]
...
\end{figure}
```

The `[H]` requires the float package, of course.

Comment: This looks like a terribly convoluted way to just disable breaking for the theorem, for which a simpler way is to pass `nobreak=true`.