# How can I achieve writing text in latex thesis/report in highlighting block?

Tags: highlighting, thesis, report

I want to highlight some text in a block just as we are able to do so in latex beamer template or as we can see notes section in many books which has a box highlighted and perhaps have different background and fonts just like notes section in books.

I have already followed the answer for [How to highlight an entire paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59340/how-to-highlight-an-entire-paragraph) but those are to just change background color which is not sufficient to me.

the text I want to make highlight may or may not contain math block / equation or inline equation but will definitely contain `\begin{itemize}...\end{itemize}` block

Comment: your question is not very clear. please show us a sketch. how you like to highlight a text. it might be that `tcolorbox` package can provide what you looking for.

Comment: There are many similar questions on the site, if not exact duplicates. See [framed or colored box with text and margin notes](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/179197) or [Inspired beautiful box from Indesign](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/281375) or [How to make a colored rounded text box?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/173008). For boxed theorems see [theorems and definitions boxes (numbering should be chapter-wise)](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/369430). For more on box  packages see [What are the relative strong and weak points between tcolorbox and mdframed?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135871/2693)

Comment: also thanks @Zarko `tcolorbox` is perfect and what I wanted. As I was ready to adapt any basic box I didn't added any sketch because I don't need to design any specific style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following @Zarko suggestion, here is  a very small overview of what we could do   with  the `tcolorbox` package.

**Update** to use `draftwatermark` package

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage {tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text 
\tcbset{standard jigsaw,opacityback=0.5}
\SetWatermarkColor{red}
\begin {document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=purple,coltext=blue]
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}

some normal text \tcbox[nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,colback=blue!30]{very important text} more normal text

\begin{tcolorbox}[ams equation]
a=b=\tcbhighmath{c}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end {document}
```

[image]

Comment: after applying this solution I just realized that it is also hiding watermark too. Is there any way to preserve watermark text I use with `\usepackage{draftwatermark}` using `\SetWatermarkText`?

Comment: @Gahan, this is expected because `drawftmark` is behind a text and it is covered by any nontransparent element. to see it through `tcolorbox` you need to make it semi or similar transparent. see `tcolorbox` documentation how to do this.

Comment: @Zarko I tried to add exact block of documentation `\begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw,colframe=red,
opacityframe=0.5, opacityback=0.5]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}` but transperency is not appearing

Comment: @Gahan, hm, i didn't check a documentation, so i can't say anything particular now. the best would be to ask new question where with some *mwe* demonstrate your problem. so more people will see your problem and will be able to help you.

Comment: @Gahan Answer updated