# Creating a specific theorem style

Tags: theorems, mdframed

I was wondering how to create a theorem environment similar to the following example: [image]

Specifically, the environment should resemble the box that contains "Claim -- The function g is linear".

This comes from a [document written by Evan Chen](http://web.evanchen.cc/exams/USAMO-2018-notes.pdf), who has his style files uploaded [here.](https://github.com/vEnhance/dotfiles/blob/master/texmf/tex/latex/evan/evan.sty) I have tried to mimic what I believed to be the relevant code (as there's a lot of stuff there that isn't related to this), to no avail. I have attached my attempt below, but it may be better to ignore it.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
    \mdfdefinestyle{mdgreenbox}{%
        linewidth=0.5pt,
        skipabove=12pt,
        frametitleaboveskip=5pt,
        frametitlebelowskip=0pt,
        skipbelow=2pt,
        frametitlefont=\bfseries,
        innertopmargin=4pt,
        innerbottommargin=8pt,
        nobreak=true,
        backgroundcolor=SpringGreen!15,
        rightline=false,
        leftline=false,
        topline=false,
        bottomline=false,
        linecolor=green,
    }
    \declaretheoremstyle[
        headfont=\bfseries\color{OliveGreen},
        mdframed={style=mdgreenbox},
        headpunct={\\[3pt]},
        postheadspace={0pt},
    ]{thmgreenbox}
\declaretheorem[style=thmgreenbox]{thrm1}
```

This returns an error, one for xcolor not recognizing the colors, and the following.

```
l.17        \mdfdefinestyle
                      {mdgreenbox}{%
The package mdframed has already been loaded with options:
  []
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [framemethod=TikZ]
Adding the global options:
  ,framemethod=TikZ
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.

Package thmtools Info: Key `mdframed' (with value `style=mdgreenbox')
(thmtools)             is not a known style key.
(thmtools)             Will pass this to every \declaretheorem
(thmtools)             that uses `style=thmgreenbox' on input line 39.
Package thmtools Info: Automatically pulling in `thmdef-mdframed' on input line 40.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmdef-mdframed.sty
Package: thmdef-mdframed 2014/04/21 v66
)
\c@thrm1=\count282
(/compile/output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.
```

I am looking for a way to mimic the environment more than to fix my methods.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at `tcolorbox`.

Comment: The obvious and immediate issues with your code are that you load the package `mdframed` twice (and with conflicting options, which causes an error): You have `\usepackage{mdframed}` and then a bit later `\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}`. You should probably remove the first of those calls. The colours are not recognised because you loaded `xcolor` without an additional option to provide more colours, you probably want to load it as `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` or `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}` for `SpringGreen` to work.

Comment: Other than that I agree with JouleV that `tcolorbox` is worth a look. It does a similar job as `mdframed` but offers a lot more options (at least that's what I think). `tcolorbox` is also still being actively maintained, whereas `mdframed` development has stalled in recent years (that need not necessarily be a bad thing, but it could mean that you are on your own when you find bugs or want a new feature). See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135871/35864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using the `tcolorbox` package as suggested by @JouleV :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem{myclaim}{Claim --\ }{
   coltitle=purple,
   colback=blue!10,
   colframe=green!70!blue,
   detach title,
   boxrule=0pt,
   leftrule=2pt,
  attach title to upper,
   sharp corners,
   left=1mm,
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{myclaim*}{}
 The function $g$ is linear
\end{myclaim*}
\end{document}
```

[image]