# Is it possible to make this tip box using the tcolorbox package?

Tags: tcolorbox

Is it possible to make the ‘tip box’ in the photograph below using the tcolorbox package (or any other way for that matter)?[image]
My abilities in tcolorbox are severely lacking, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Look into the manual (search for `leftrule`).

Comment: Look to this [may be similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475946/creating-a-specific-theorem-style/475952#475952)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how we can do it with a `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mytcolorbox}[1]{
   enhanced,
   colback=white,
   colframe=gray,
   coltitle=black,
   fonttitle=\bfseries\LARGE,
   detach title,
   boxrule=2pt,
   leftrule=0pt,
   top=1mm,
  attach title to upper={\par},
   sharp corners,
   borderline west={5pt}{0pt}{red!70!blue},
   title=#1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytcolorbox}{Tip Box Title}
 \lipsum[1-2]
\end{mytcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you change the border color as in the posted image?

Comment: @Sigur Is the border color correct ?

Comment: I think is good. Congs.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda Perfect, thank you very much!