# Which package for shading theorems: tcolorbox, mdframed, or just thmtools?

Tags: tcolorbox, theorems, mdframed, thmtools

What are the comparative advantages and disadvantages of each of the following packages for creating shaded backgrounds of theorem-like environments produced using `thmtools`: `tcolorbox`, `mdframed`, and just `thmtools` itself with its `shaded` key?

(I do know already that `thmtools` with its `shaded` key does not allow theorem-like environments to extend over a page break.)

Comment: There's also the `framed` package, which defines a `shaded` environment, which works well with `ntheorem`.

Comment: `tcolorbox`, with its `breakable` libarary, is preferable, especially when the theorem-like env will "extend over a page break".

Comment: Similar question: [What are the relative strong and weak points between tcolorbox and mdframed? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135871/what-are-the-relative-strong-and-weak-points-between-tcolorbox-and-mdframed)