# Broken description environment

Tags: mdframed, description, beamerarticle

Look at the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
  
\surroundwithmdframed{definition}


\begin{document}
  \begin{definition}
    \alert{test}
    \begin{description}
      \item[A:] TestA
      \item[B:] TestB
    \end{description}
  \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

It produces:
[image: pic for wrong typesetting of description environment]

Any ideas for fixing it?

Comment: Have you considered another kind of box, e.g. a tcolorbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mdframed` package is basically abandoned, because in the meantime `tcolorbox` has appeared, which is much more powerful.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcolorboxenvironment{definition}{
  boxrule=0.5pt,
  sharp corners,
  colback=white,
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{definition}
    \alert{test}
    \begin{description}
      \item[A:] TestA
      \item[B:] TestB
    \end{description}
  \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I wouldn't use `beamerarticle`, but it's personal opinion.

Comment: Why not use `beamerarticle`? Does it has some big disadvantages?

Comment: @Stephen I firmly believe that a paper is a very different thing than a presentation.

Comment: I think so too, but who says it will be used in a paper? To have a simple combination of lecture slides and lecture notes, I think this is an adequate solution. Or would you disagree here?

Comment: Just for cross reference a recent discussion on `tcolorbox` vs. `mdframed`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135871/what-are-the-relative-strong-and-weak-points-between-tcolorbox-and-mdframed

Answer (score 5):

With `tcolorbox` it works:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{definition}{\begin{tcolorbox}[boxrule=1pt]}
\AfterEndEnvironment{definition}{\end{tcolorbox}}


\begin{document}
  \begin{definition}
    \alert{test}
    \begin{description}
      \item[A:] TestA
      \item[B:] TestB
    \end{description}
  \end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image: tcolorbox working picture]