# Creating an example environment structured exactly like amsthm's proof environment

Tags: environments, amsthm

I want to create an environment for examples that is structured exactly like the `\begin{proof}...\end{proof}` environment, i.e. starting with an italic "Example.", continuing in the same line and ending with a particular symbol to the far right, e.g. `\clubsuit`.

Edit: I am using `amsthm` package.

How do I do that, i.e. what is the code to be inserted at the beginning?

Comment: you could clone the `proof` environment, or you might get some help from this answer: [Indicator at end of theorem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146197/579).

Comment: Hi, I do not know what it means to "clone" an environment. I have tried an analogous application of the solution provided in the thread you posted but that doesn't work, because apparently the commands \proofstyle and \newproof do not exist. I am sorry, I'm a greenhorn when it comes to things like defining my own stuff. :(

Comment: I guess the `ntheorem` and `thmtools` packages can help a lot. They are a lot more flexible than `amsthm`. Could you indicate whether it is an option for you to use another package, instead of `amsthm`?

Comment: Do you need to number the examples?

Comment: Hi egreg, no that is not necessary. Just as simple as I described above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this example illustrates what i meant by "cloning" the `amsthm` `proof` environment.
it retains the ability to use `\qedhere` to "move the end-symbol up" when the environment ends with a list or display math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\examplesymbol}{\ensuremath\clubsuit}
\newenvironment{example}[1][\examplename]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \begingroup
  \let\qedsymbol\examplesymbol
      \trivlist

  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
  \endgroup
}
\providecommand{\examplename}{Example}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
This is a proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{example}
This is an example.  It looks like a proof.
\end{example}


\begin{example}
This example ends with a list.
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1;
\item item 2. \qedhere
\end{itemize}
\end{example}

\begin{example}
This example ends with display math.
\[
x + y = z
\qedhere
\]
\end{example}

\begin{proof}
Another proof
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

there are other ways to do this, but they are manual.  one such uses the "optional header" feature of the `proof` environment, and resets the end-symbol just before it is used.

```
\begin{proof}[Example]
[...]
\let\qedsymbol\examplesymbol
\end{proof}
```

if `\qedhere` is needed, precede it directly by the `\let\qedsymbol` substitution.