# changing font style/size for proof, adding a square after example

Tags: fonts, symbols, environments, fontsize

Is is possible to change font size/(or style) for a proof? I was also thinking to add a small hollow square at the end of every example to separate the text a little. Something similar that works like \qedhere symbol.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paperfootinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\titleformat{\section}
 {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{chngcntr}%added to reset footnote for each chapter
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}%added to reste footnote for each chapter 
\marginsize{0.1\paperwidth}{0.1\paperheight}{2cm}{2cm}
\newcommand{\bigslant}[2]{{\raisebox{.2em}{$#1$}\left/\raisebox{-.2em}{$#2$}\right.}}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter] % reset theorem numbering for each chapter
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition} % definition numbers are dependent on theorem numbers
\newtheorem{exmp}[thm]{Example}
\theoremstyle{corollary}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{lemma}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{proposition}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newcommand{\ndiv}{\hspace{-4pt}\not|\hspace{2pt}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\disc}{disc}
%\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\rule{0.7em}{0.7em}}
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\RectangleBold}
\def\quotient#1#2{%
    \raise1ex\hbox{$#1$}\Big/\lower1ex\hbox{$#2$}%
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\order}{\mathcal{O}_{K}} %defined myself
\DeclareMathOperator{\z}{\mathbb{Z}} %defined myself
\DeclareMathOperator{\q}{\mathbb{Q}} %defined myself
\DeclareMathOperator{\C}{\mathbb{C}} %defined myself
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This is my proof
\end{proof}
\begin{exmp}
Want a hollow square at the end of this example.
\end{exmp}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Comment: take a look at this answer: [Denoting the end of example/remark](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32394/579)  another example: [Creating an example environment structured exactly like amsthm's proof environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148069/579)

Comment: Thank you Barbara, I managed to fixed the symbol by using one of these answers. Do you have any idea how to can I change the size of the font (or the style) just for proofs? Thank you.

Comment: you're using some theorem styles that i'm not familiar with, and i know know where the solid tombstone came from, so this is just "blue sky".  since `proof` defines a "contained" environment, any font you reset within it will "go away" when you leave the environment.  so you could use (for example) `\small` or `\large` or `\itshape` locally within the environment.  you would have to use the optional proof name to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy with `thmtools`:

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
%  a5paper,% really?
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true
]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter] % reset theorem numbering for each chapter
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition} % definition numbers are dependent on theorem numbers

\declaretheoremstyle[
  style=definition,
  qed=\openbox,
]{example}
\declaretheorem[
  name=Example,
  style=example,
  numberlike=thm,
]{exmp}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\RectangleBold}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
This is my proof
\end{proof}
\begin{exmp}
Want a hollow square at the end of this example.
\end{exmp}
\end{document}
```

I have removed the inessential parts of the preamble. Note that there is no `lemma`, `corollary` or `proposition` theorem style. A full specification with `thmtools` would be

```
\documentclass[
  11pt,
%  a5paper,% really?
  footinclude=true,
  headinclude=true
]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  name=Theorem,
  within=chapter,
]{thm}
\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  name=Lemma,
  numberlike=thm,
]{lem}
\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  name=Proposition,
  numberlike=thm,
]{prop}
\declaretheorem[
  style=plain,
  name=Corollary,
  numberlike=thm,
]{cor}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\declaretheorem[
  style=definition,
  name=Definition,
  numberlike=thm,
]{defn}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  style=definition,
  qed=\openbox,
]{example}
\declaretheorem[
  name=Example,
  style=example,
  numberlike=thm,
]{exmp}

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{\RectangleBold}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title}
\begin{prop}
A proposition.
\end{prop}
\begin{lem}
A lemma.
\end{lem}
\begin{thm}
A theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
This is my proof
\end{proof}
\begin{cor}
A corollary.
\end{cor}
\begin{exmp}
Want a hollow square at the end of this example.
\end{exmp}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg, this is exactly what I am after but somehow the code you have suggested does not want to work with the rest of my text, I just get a bunch of errors....especially with newly declared math operators

Comment: @user124471 I used only the package necessary for the example; for `\DeclareMathOperator` you need `amsmath`.

Comment: How do I get a ongoing numbering (for Lemmas and Proposition,.. , each) on a document level with a dot behind the number?

Answer (score 1):

As an example environment I use (something like) the following:

```
\newenvironment{Example}[1][\relax]%
  {\refstepcounter{equation}\trivlist
   \ifx#1\relax
     \item[\hskip\labelsep\theequation.~\textbf{Example}\space]
    \else
     \item[\hskip\labelsep\theequation.~\textbf{Example }(#1)\space]
   \fi
   \ignorespaces
  }{\unskip\nobreak\hfil%
    \penalty50\hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil$\diamondsuit$%
    \parfillskip=0pt\finalhyphendemerits=0\penalty-100\endtrivlist%
}
```

If you wanted to change the font etc used in the `proof` environment then you can hijack it with something like this:

```
\newenvironment{Proof}[1][Proof]{\proof[#1]\large\itshape}{\endproof}
```

Now the proof is written in a large italic font.

Comment: How can i just chane the the layout of "Proof of Lemma x" and have the rest as before?